# Upgrade Mongo DB - Unsupported WiredTiger File Version

Tags: mongodb, ubuntu

Previously, I made an mistake by upgrade Mongo DB from 3.4 directly to 4.0. It caused some errors. I successfully downgraded to 3.4 again and try to improve the data compatibility by upgrading it to 3.6 first.

When I want to run Mongo DB 3.6, it return this error

```
unsupported WiredTiger file version: this build  only supports major/minor versions up to 2,  and the file is version 3: WT_ERROR: non-specific WiredTiger error
```

I use mmapv1 engine and change it tow WiredTiger, it still return same error. What should I do to upgrade my Mongo DB to 3.6. I'm struggling to do it.